# multiple webviews in Android

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an application in which I would like to create different webViews in some conditions. Despite having more than one webView, the idea is to show only one of them.

I have seen that the best way is create a new class which extends Activity.

This is the main class

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This is the second class I have done to create new Webviews

```
  public class WebScreen extends Activity { 
        private WebView myWebView; 


  @Override 
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
       this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS); 

    } 

    public void onClick(View arg0) { 
      return; 
     } 

     @Override 
     protected void onPause() { 
       myWebView = null; 
      super.onPause(); 
      } 

      @Override 
      protected void onStart(){  
       }

      @Override 
       protected void onResume() { 
          super.onResume(); 
          myWebView = new WebView(this); 
          myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
          myWebView.loadUrl("myURL"); 
          setContentView(myWebView); 
       }   

        @Override 
        public void onBackPressed() { 
          super.onBackPressed();
          myWebView = null; 
         }
```

Comment: just use webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) for the one you want to show and View.GONE or View.Invisible for the one you dont want to see.

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you have used a layout on your first activity `setContentView(R.layout.main);`. You have to set another layout on the `WebScreen.onCreate`. p.e.

myweblayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Set it at onCreate

```
setContentView(R.layout.myweblayout)
```

And get the tag from the activity using

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

I suggest you to read [Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#AddingWebView)

Answer (score 0):

You can create two webviews in the same activity and same xml file,just keep the visibility of one of the views as gone and one as visible .You can always switch between the views by changing the visibilities.